# How to query_string with multiple condition?

Tags: elasticsearch, thai

I have query code like this.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "content_normalization:*ชื่นชม*" 
        }
    }
}
```

And I cannot use "match" in thai language (I don't know why).
I want to search in one field which contains text "ชื่นชม" but it doesn't contain text "ครับ".

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "content_normalization:*ชื่นชม*"
          }
        }],
        "must_not":[
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "content_normalization:*ครับ*"
          }}]}}}
```